# If $f(x)=1+x+\int_1^x(\ln^2t+2\ln t)dt$,then $f(x)$ increases in

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=1+x+\int_1^x(\ln^2t+2\ln t)dt$,then $f(x)$ increases in
$(A)(0,\infty)$
$(B)(0,e^{-2})\cup(1,\infty)$
$(C)$no value
$(D)(1,\infty)$

---

$f'(x)=1+\ln^2x+2\ln x=(\ln x+1)^2>0$.
So $f(x)$ is increasing throughout its domain of definition,we need to find the domain of $f(x).$
$f(x)=1+x+\int_1^x(\ln^2t+2\ln t)dt$
As the lower limit is $1$,so upper limit is greater than lower limit.
So doamin of $f(x)$ is $x>1$.I chose $(D)$ as answer,but in my book $(A)$ is given as correct answer.I do not know where i have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper limit of integration is not required to be greater than the lower limit of integration.

Recall that
$$\int_a^b g(x) \, dx = -\int_b^a g(x) \, dx.$$

Your analysis of $f'(x)$ is correct and it holds true for all $x>0$.   The domain of $f(x)$ is the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: How is the domain of $f(x)$ the set of positive real numbers,why not negative reals also.@tilper

Comment: @user1557 because of the natural log functions in the integrand.  The domain of the natural log function is the set of all positive reals, and you can't integrate a function outside of its domain.  Therefore the limits of integration must be in the domain of the integrand (technically we can have a limit on the boundary of the domain but that's a story for another day), and the integrand's domain is $(0, +\infty).$

Comment: In $f(x)=1+x+\int_1^x(\ln^2t+2\ln t)dt$,the log function is inside the integral sign,so will integral sign not affect the domain of $f(x)$

Comment: @user1557 I edited my previous reply in a way that will address that question.  Even if it's inside the integral (i.e., if it's the integrand) you still need to worry about the domain.